# How to repro user's experience?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I've provided a couple of users with an ad hoc copy of my app.  They sync fine but the app crashes just after loading.  I've tried everything I can think of to repro it and everything always goes just fine for me.  I've removed all profiles from my phone and removed them from the library\mobiledevices folder.  No matter what I do, the app starts fine.  Any ideas how I can repro the user's experience?

From crash logs, this is similar:
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2097721

And from this site:
http://blog.redfin.com/devblog/2009/09/installing_beta_builds_on_iphone.html

I get this output:

```
MacBook:buildoutput auser$ codesign -vvvv myapp.app
myapp.app: cannot find code object on disk
```

If I do this for release or debug builds, the output is:

```
myapp.app: valid on disk
myapp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

Still, why doesn't it crash on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you ask them for their [crash reports?](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html#ACQUIRING_CRASH_REPORTS)

Answer (score 1):

Ask for an image of their environment.  Or ask them and hope they don't forget some seemingly arbitrary detail.  Then perform the test again.